# Inject constructor argument Spring Resource file with Grails/Groovy

Tags: spring, grails, groovy, resources, classpath

From our Grails/Groovy app we need to use a service from a legacy Java service class, the constructor of which has a parameter of type org.springframework.core.io.Resource, e.g.

```
public ServiceClass(Resource someResource)
```

We need to inject an instance of the service class into a Groovy class of our app using Spring DSL, with the Resource referring to an XML file within our /src/main/resources. I tried to create the Spring config for this purpose, but so far I couldn't find a working solution. The relevant part of the config file looks like this

```
beans = {
    xmlns aop:"http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop",
    sec:"http://www.springframework.org/schema/security",
    context:"http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"

    serviceClass(com.somepackage.ServiceClass) {
      //here we need to refer to the constructor arg XML file some way
    }
}
```

I have tried multiple syntaxes found in various tutorials, e.g. closure for beanDefinition.constructorArgs, but unfortunately without success so far. Although neither the app compilation (grails:war) nor the startup (grails:run-app) indicates any problems with the bean wiring, when the app is actually loaded into the browser, we receive a NPE stating that our Groovy class into which the service class is injected, is a null object. So it seems that the bean wiring was not successful after all. Any help is appreciated

Comment: i assume you read http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/spring.html#theBeanBuilderDSLExplained ``Constructor arguments can be defined using parameters to each bean-defining method. Put them after the first argument (the Class):

bb.beans {
    exampleBean(MyExampleBean, "firstArgument", 2) {
        someProperty = [1, 2, 3]
    }
}``

Comment: and also you still can use a ``resources.xml`` beside the groovy one, if you feel better writing XML

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I read the mentioned document and tried this syntax too before asking the question, but then it did not work either. However, it turned out that the main problem was with the project setup itself, after the fixing of which the issue is now solved; either this approach or using bean.constructorArgs in closure seems to be OK

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After fixing various issues with the project setup itself and multiple cleanups/recompiles, it seems that the following two approaches are both OK

```
serviceClass(com.somepackage.ServiceClass, '/WEB-INF/constructor-arg-xml-file.xml') {}
```

and

```
serviceClass(com.somepackage.ServiceClass) { bean ->
        bean.constructorArgs = [
            '/WEB-INF/constructor-arg-xml-file.xml'
        ]
    }
```